# Accumulation points of sets with non-Euclidian metrics

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

This question is motivated by a homework problem that I was given this week, specifically this one:

Consider the metric space $(X\times X,d_\infty$) where $d_\infty=((a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)):=max(d(a_1,a_2),d(b_1,b_2))$. Let Ac(Y) denote the set of accumulation points of $Y\subset X$. Is it true that $Ac(A\times B)=Ac(A)\times Ac(B)$

Note: $d$ here is the euclidian metric.

How would one rigorously find the accumulation points of a set such as $(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q},d_\infty)$. I would postulate that the accumulation points would be $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})$ if the metric was $d$ instead of $d_\infty$. Since $d_\infty$ is a non-Euclidan metric I am not sure however. Simply put I am aksing for a procedure to find accumulation points of metric spaces with non-Euclidian metrics.

Comment: You can find a ball in the Euclidean metric that is contained within a ball with the Chebyshev metric and vice versa so their topological properties are the same. Try to reason geometrically using these balls to structure your proof.